# Bootstrap 4 dropdown - automatic width sizing?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-4

Since [Bootstrap 4 auto columns](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/#auto-layout-columns) can adapt to whatever width is needed to fill a row, I thought I'd use it to populate a dropdown menu that may have 1 or 2 columns depending on user location.

The problem is the dropdown width does not expand to accommodate more than 1 column. When I add the second column it simply displays under the first, and if I change the class from "col" to "col-6" they display side by side but the contents of the columns overlap.

Setting an explicit width for the menu isn't an option since if I make it wide enough for 2 columns it will be unnecessarily wide when only 1 column is displayed.

How can I achieve a dropdown menu that will adapt to the width of it's contents, and to the width needed for another column when present?

Demo of the problem:
https://www.bootply.com/VH5uvew6eQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole Bootstrap grid system is predicated on the idea that the parent of a `.row` has a determined width (typically provided by a `.container` or `.container-fluid`) and `.row` helps you divide that `width`.

It is designed to constrain/stretch column contents, not to accommodate the `auto` width of its columns, so that it provides your layout with some sense of order. Indeed, v4 is more flexible than previous versions, as it allows you to divide the space with a certain amount of flexibility (using flexbox) but, still, within the confines of its provided size.

If you don't need that, don't use the grid system for your particular element. Only use it where it makes sense.

In your case, adding a `double` class to the dropdowns you want enlarged and overriding Bootstrap's `.dropdown-menu: min-width: 10rem` with your own

```
.dropdown-menu.double { min-width: 20rem; }
```

and perhaps adding `no-gutters` class to your `row`s might be [a step forward](https://www.bootply.com/O6yazBIHw7) towards your goal.

***Do*** note your layout has multiple duplicated ids which are invalid HTML.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the grid rules regarding rows, containers and widths, it now seems obvious.